# WCF RIA Services Issue With Updating

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-sql, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am running into an issue with refreshing data on a page after doing an update through WCF RIA Services.

I have a ComboBox and a Button on a page. The user chooses an item from the ComboBox, and then clicks the Button. This does a soft delete of the item in the database(setting "Active" = false). However, I would like for it to be removed from the ComboBox after the updated has completed. This is where my problem is.

```
InventorySystemDomainContext context = new InventorySystemDomainContext();

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Cigarette c = cboCigarette.SelectedItem as Cigarette;
    c.Active = false;

    SubmitOperation so = context.SubmitChanges();
    so.Completed += delegate (object s, EventArgs es)
    {
        LoadComboBox();
    }
}

private void LoadComboBox()
{
    cboCigarettes.DataSource = null;
    cboCigarettes.DataSource = context.Cigarettes;
    context.Load(context.GetCigarettesQuery());
}
```

When the Delete button is clicked, all the code runs. However, the deleted item is still in the ComboBox(even though the record has been updated in the database). If I refresh the page, the item is gone from the ComboBox.

Any ideas?

PS: I wrote this code from memory since I don't have the code with me. So I may have forgotten a line, but I think I got all the relevant lines.

Comment: Does context.GetCigarettesQuery() returns query that excludes inactive items from resultset? (something like Cigarettes.Where(c => !c.Active))

Comment: Yes it does.  The `LoadComboBox` method is executed in the Window_Loaded event.  When I refresh the page after the delete, the deleted item is now gone from the ComboBox.  I would like for this to occur without having to refresh the entire page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the ComboBox.ItemsSource to the Entities collection return from the Load method? EntitySets (context.Cigarettes) are aggregating (they contain data from multiple loads) while LoadOperation.Entities is not (it only contains data from the load it represents).

Comment: I have not tried that.  I didn't know there was a difference.  I will try that.

Comment: The downside to this solution is that the Grid "Blinks" / reloads completely. Calling Remove on the collection causes the entity to be deleted when SubmitChanges is called. Wonder if you could detach the entity in question and then remove it.... just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the accepted solution is that the collection is now disconnected, which messes with the built in elegance of adding and removing bound items.

Perhaps a better solution would be to detach the entity in question after the soft delete

```
InventorySystemDomainContext context = new InventorySystemDomainContext();

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Cigarette c = cboCigarette.SelectedItem as Cigarette;
    c.Active = false;

    SubmitOperation so = context.SubmitChanges(OnCigaretteSaved, null);
}

private void OnCigaretteSaved(SubmitOperation so)
{
    context.Cigarettes.Detach(context.Cigarettes.Where(item => item.Active == false).First());
}

private void LoadComboBox()
{
    cboCigarettes.DataSource = null;
    cboCigarettes.DataSource = context.Cigarettes;
    context.Load(context.GetCigarettesQuery());
}
```